# Number of elements in float array in C

Tags: c, arrays, size

i have array of float in C. the length of this array depends of user input. I need to find out number of elements in this array. Example:

```
float a[10] = {3.1314, 1.5131, 9.133,  10.333}
```

How can i check number of elements? sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) always give the max number of elements (10 in this case).

Comment: The number of elements is actually `10`.

Answer (score 5):

The number of elements in an array of type `T[N]` is `N` by definition. So your array, of type `float[10]`, has 10 elements, the first four are set to some values, the rest are set to `0.0f`. If you want to check how many elements have been set, you'll have to set the rest to some sentinel value that is not a valid value to "set". Or you can keep track of the number of set elements separately.

Comment: Why doesn't work the same way as int array and char array? Because when i iterate i get different result every time.

for (int i = 0; i < 13 && a[i] != 0; i++){
printf("\n%f",a[i]);}

Comment: @Quba It works exactly the same as an `int` or `char` array. You're misinterpreting your results. You're just looping over elements until you find one with a certain value (0). You could carry on looping until the end of the array but you chose not to.

Comment: @Quba You are using a sentinel (the int or char value 0). You *can* work the same way, as juanchpanza pointed out. Maybe the value 0.0, in case it makes sense, or NaN, or anything that fits.

Comment: Thx guys. i just did it at start and now it works :):
 for ( int i = 0; i < 13; i++){

 a[i] = 0;

}

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, using sizeof won't do the trick. For example, sizeof(a)/sizeof(float) will just give you 10.

I'd use a buffer struct:

```
#define MAX_NBR_OF_ELEMENTS 10

typedef struct {
    float a[MAX_NBR_OF_ELEMENTS];
    size_t count;
} FloatBuffer;
```

For each user-entered float, add it to the struct array and increase count to keep track of how many floats have been entered into the array.

```
FloatBuffer floatBuff;

void AddFloatToBuffer(float val)
{
    if(count < MAX_NBR_OF_ELEMENTS)
    {
        floatBuff.a[count] = val;
        floatBuff.count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`

will give 10 because

`float a[10] = {3.1314, 1.5131, 9.133,  10.333}`

initializes all non explicit (other) elements to `0.0f`

you will have iterate to find non-zero elements

Comment: ... and what's if 0.0 is an application valid value!? I'm not sure if it is standard, but exist also NAN (that is defined in math.h) ... But also that might be an application valid value. Then I think the better solution is to keep track of the number inserted in the vector!

Answer (score 0):

You declared an array `10` `float`. It means this array will contain `10` `float` elements. Initializer will initialize its four elements with the value provided and rest will be initialized with `0.0` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 void numel(int array1[100][100])
    {
        int count=0,row,column;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
            {
                if(array1[i][j]!='\0') 
                {
                    count++;
                    //printf("\n%d-%d",array1[i][j],count);
                }
                else 
                {
                    column++;
                    break;
                }
            }

    }   
    printf("count=%d",count);
}
int main()
{   
    int r,arr[100][100]={0},c;
    printf("Enter the no. of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("\nEnter the no. of columns: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("\nEnter the elements: ");
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    numel(arr);
}
```